# Getting UIKeyboard Height When TextField Shows

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a couple UITextFields that will be hidden by the keyboard when it pops up, so I implemented the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and sent them to their respective methods:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGFloat height = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    keyBoardHeight = height;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGFloat height = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;
    keyBoardHeight = height;
}
```

I then have my textfields delegating to this method:

```
//TextFieldDelegate
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    float keyboardOffset = [self offsetForKeyboard:textField.frame.origin.y withHeight:textField.frame.size.height];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", keyBoardHeight, keyboardOffset);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
    self.view.frame = [Global rect:self.view.frame withNewY:-[self offsetForKeyboard:textField.frame.origin.y withHeight:textField.frame.size.height]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The code runs properly, but when I run the code, the `keyboardWillShow:` method runs **after** the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method. Because of this, `keyboardHeight` is set to 0 the first time the code runs, and so the offset I calculate is way off.

How can I make the `keyboardWillShow:` method run **before** the `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method? Is there another delegate method that I can use instead?

Comment: You may wish to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah that's the question that I looked up that inspired me to write a catch-all for any text field. I figured it out though. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but no there's no way to do that. You have to do your animations or whatever you do for keyboard handling **inside the notification observer**.
Here's what Apple recommends and works fine for me in all cases I've encountered upto now.

[Apple's Keyboard Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is trying to do this, I found a way:

Maintain a weak reference to the currently editing text field:

```
UITextField* editingTextField;

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    editingTextField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    editingTextField = nil;
}
```

Then just reference the weak text field while it is open in the `keyboardWillShow:` method to calculate the appropriate offsets and move the view accordingly.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    //Use editingTextField's frame here
}
```

Comment: That's what I said in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use IQKeyboardManager. It is a single line code for all textfield in any view.Link: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager